# CSS Navigation Bar Not Flush With Browser

Tags: html, css

I am building a navigation bar. This is what the HTML looks like

```
<div class="navhead">TEXT</div>
<div class="navcontainer">
<a href="#"><div class="button">TEXT</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="button">TEXT</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="button">TEXT</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="button">TEXT</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="button">TEXT</div></a>
</div>
```

And this is what the CSS looks like.

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:"futura";
    margin-top:75px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.navcontainer {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#FFF;
    height:60px;
    top:24px;
    border:solid;
    color:#000;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:solid;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.button {
    width:20%;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:central;
    line-height:60px;
    transition:background-color 1.5s ease;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.button:hover {
    width:20%;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:central;
    line-height:60px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.navhead {
    width:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    height:24px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:9px;
    line-height:24px;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the last button to the right isn't flush with the browser window. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I added everything I thought I needed to the "body" class, but still there's space... I mean, there's no space on top of it, just to the right of the last button.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XKx2V/)

Comment: It looks ok in my Firefox. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Looks fine in my safari.

Comment: You could try simplifying the code, how does this look: http://jsfiddle.net/XKx2V/6/

Comment: It looks fine to me, too...

Comment: I can confirm that in firefox, the 'result' button in the upper right is cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better way to structure your HTML and a more reliable way to create that menu: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/xaGuq

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:"futura";
    margin-top:75px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.navcontainer {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#FFF;
    top:24px;
    border:solid;
    color:#000;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:solid;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.navcontainer li {display: table-cell;}

.navcontainer li a {line-height: 60px; 
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center; 
    transition:background-color 1.5s ease;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navcontainer li a:hover {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}

.navhead {
    width:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    height:24px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:9px;
    line-height:24px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navhead">TEXT</div>
<ul class="navcontainer">
<li>
    <a href="#">TEXT</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">TEXT</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">TEXT</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">TEXT</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">TEXT</a>
</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```